# Azure function in C# to invoke a powershell command on a specific VM?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I'm fairly new to this and I'm not sure what I'm doing.  I have a bunch of Azure functions written in C# set up and working for my application.  I have a VM in the same resource group and I can run a powershell script on that VM to do what I want.

My question is, how do I invoke my powershell script on a specific VM from my function?

Comment: You mentioned that your Functions are written in C#. Does this mean that your C# Function code contains PowerShell script code that it intended to be executed on a VM?

Comment: The function apps I have set up right now mostly do database work.  They could call powershell if there's a reasonable way to call a script on a specific VM.

Comment: I see. It’s possible for your C# script to send a request your target VM to run the PowerShell script on that VM provided that that VM is able to accept that request (preferably with proper auth setup). One caveat is that in Consumption Plan, your Function execution has a timeout of 5 mins, configurable to a max of 10 mins so your workflow needs to take that into account. In App Service Plan, there is no such time restrictions if you turn on “AlwayOn”

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did basically manage to get this working as you said. I wrote a Run book to access the vm and install and run a custom script extension with my PowerShell script. It's a pretty terrible way of doing things though. I'm likely going to approach this from a different perspective. Likely exposing the vm and writing a Windows service to handle the work. It's a shame Azure doesn't have easier methods to integrate vm's.